# Survey papers in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Can somebody recommend a good survey paper (or something similar to it) for real analysis?

I'm looking for something much shorter than a $200$ page text-book, but should still tell what the main topics are with their short descriptions.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I doubt such a survey paper exists. In general, survey papers are primarily written when an area of mathematics is sufficiently developed that more than a handful of people are involved in it, but whose literature is still in a state of disarray (due to different notation, different assumptions for basic constructions, fragmented literature, etc.). This is definitely not the case for an area that contains several tens of thousands of research papers and many hundreds of textbooks.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have said I'm looking for a short introduction. I see no reason why they shouldn't exist.

Comment: If you could give some details about your background and interests, I might be able to think of something. Real analysis is what I did my Ph.D. work in and I'm fairly knowledgeable about the literature in this area . . .